# Evaluate $\int_{S}\frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}dV$, where $S$ is the region between $x^2+y^2+z^2=2z$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates

I have evaluated $\int_{S}\frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}dV$, where $S$ is the region bounded below by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2z$ and above by the sphere  $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

Using spherical coordinates I get:

\begin{align*}
\int_{S}\frac{z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}dV&=\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{\phi=\pi/3}\int_{\rho=1/2\sec(\phi)}^{\rho=1}\frac{\rho\cos(\phi)}{\rho^3}\rho^2\sin(\phi)d\rho d\phi d\theta\\&+\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}\int_{\phi=\pi/3}^{\phi=\pi/2}\int_{\rho=0}^{\rho=2\cos(\phi)}\frac{\rho\cos(\phi)}{\rho^3}\rho^2\sin(\phi)d\rho d\phi d\theta\\
&=2\pi\int_{\phi=0}^{\phi=\pi/3}\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)[1-\frac{1}{2}\sec(\phi)]d\phi\\ &+2\pi\int_{\phi=\pi/3}^{\phi=\pi/2}\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)\cdot 2\cos(\phi)d\phi d\theta\\&=2\pi\cdot\frac{1}{8}+2\pi\cdot\frac{1}{12}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{5}{12}\pi
\end{align*}

but the book I took this exercise from says that the solution should instead be $\frac{11}{12}\pi$; even so, I cannot find my mistake so I would be grateful if someone would point out where I have gone wrong. Thanks.

Comment: In the first equation, should the second instance of $x^2$ actually be $z^2$?

Comment: @user170231 Yes, fixed, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your approach. For $0\le\phi\le\pi/3$, you should have $0\le\rho\le 1$. For $\pi/3\le\phi\le\pi/2$,  you should have $0\le\rho\le 2\cos\phi$. Why did the plane $z=1/2$ come into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is missing one integral,

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\tfrac\pi3} \int_0^{\tfrac12\sec(\phi)} \cos(\phi)\sin(\phi) \, d\rho\, d\phi \, d\theta = \frac\pi2$$

which corresponds to the space above the cone defined by $\phi=\dfrac\pi3$ and below the plane $\rho=\dfrac12 \sec(\phi)$.